# How to replace “Male” into “Female”in the dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset something like this:

[image: dataset]

How can I replace all the Male into Female using r?

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Answer (score 2):

First, welcome to Stackoverflow. As pointed in the comments, it's better to give a reproducible example. I'm happy to answer this time, but bear in mind that in the future, you are more likely to get answers if you give such an example.

I'm assuming you're working with a data frame. What you would need is:

```
> df <- data.frame("name"=c("A","B","C","D"), sex=c("Male","Male","Male","Female"))
> df
  name    sex
1    A   Male
2    B   Male
3    C   Male
4    D Female
> df$sex[df$sex == "Male"] <- "Female"
> df
  name    sex
1    A Female
2    B Female
3    C Female
4    D Female
```

The line `df$sex[df$sex == "Male"] <- "Female"` is what you are looking for. The first part, `df$sex`, selects the column named sex.

The second part, `[df$sex == "Male"]`, selects all rows of the column which have sex equal to "Male".

The last part is assignment. `<- "Female"` assigns selected observations the value "Female".

Comment: An example of a reproducible example would be the code I gave in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[sex=="Male", sex := "Female"]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$sex <- with(df, replace(sex, sex=="Male", "Female"))
```

Comment: This won't work if there are other values below (like "unknown").

Comment: @Rodrigo  okay, then i corrected it

Comment: df$sex[df$sex == "Male"] <- "Female" is shorter.

Comment: @Rodrigo  But, that is already in the other answer

Comment: So, what's the point in your answer?

Comment: @Rodrigo  I am showing the `data.table` and also a `replace` way.  Compact way is not always the best

Comment: Compact is not the best only if it's slower. Don't agree with using an external library to do what base already does, but it's good to learn a function like replace. Thank you!